# Java unsupported class version on heroku for nodejs app?

Tags: java, node.js, heroku

I have a node.js app that needs a java file to be run in the local directory. I'm running the java file using a child process and it works perfectly on local host.

However, when I try to deploy the app to heroku, I get the following error log:

[image: Error Log]

Any ideas on what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your Java code is compiled for Java 8, but it is running on Heroku with Java 7. The default JDK on the cedar-14 stack image (Heroku's base platform) is Java 7.

In order to use Java 8, you'll need to also use the Java buildpack. But since it appears you are trying to run a binary, you will only need the [base buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-jvm-common), which does not try to compile anything.

Running these commands should fix the problem for you:

```
$ heroku buildpacks:clear
$ heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-jvm-common
$ heroku buildpacks:add heroku/nodejs
```

Then redeploy. You can confirm the version of Java by running this command:

```
$ heroku run java -version
Running java -version on nameless-reef-3840... up, run.7606
openjdk version "1.8.0_66-cedar14"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-cedar14-b17)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)
```

The default version of Java for the jvm buildpack is Java 8, so you will not need any other configuration.